# Can the Cabibbo angle be negative without changing the physics?

Tags: quantum-field-theory

I am studying QFT and have come across the Cabibbo angle and the CKM matrix. The Cabibbo angle has been measured to be roughly 13 degrees which gives each component of the CKM matrix a positive value. However, I was wondering if changing the angle to -13 degrees would cause any fundamental change to the underlying physics?

To me the paradox seems to be that angles can be measured from any fixed point and whether you call it positive or negative seems a bit arbitrary. But then by changing the angle to a negative, some components of the CKM matrix will also become a negative (the ones that have a sin(theta) in them). Would this not cause a fundamental change to the physics of the quarks when the CKM matrix is applied? Or is it just a purely mathematical and arbitrary change?

Edit: I understand that the Cabibbo angle isn't actually an angle that is measured as such, but one that fits with the observations. At the moment I am leaning towards the idea that it will indeed change the physics. Is there something I am missing?

Cheers!

Comment: Two quick comments: (1) You can define angles, including the sign, by properly specifying them. (2) The Cabibbo angle, as many such parameters, is a way to satisfy a relation such as $a^2+b^2=1$. Then, if you switch the sign of the angle, you also flip the sign of $a$ (or $b$).  Whether that changes the physics may depend on whether there are additional phase freedoms you can exploit to undo this flip. Now you can check wheteher you find a physical quantity that depends on $\sin\theta_\text{C}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that it doesn't change the physics of quark mixing if you change $\theta_c$ for $-\theta_c$, as the decay rates $\Gamma$ depend on the square of the coupling strength. The decay rates are what is actually measured, so it seems nothing physical changes if $g_W\sin(\theta_c)$ -> $ -g_W\sin(\theta_c)$